# por que me sale este error en el administrador de django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

me encuentro realizando un curso de django y estoy comenzando a ver los managers, fui haciendo lo mismo que el profesor del curso, creando el proyecto, instalando los paquetes en el entorno virtual, creando e instalando las aplicaciones correspondientes, creando los models y views, y también cree la base de datos en postgresql y configure lo necesario en el archivo local.py, y al momento de probar lo que llevamos hecho e ingresar al administrador de django(porque según indico el profesor había que realizar registros a la base de datos desde al administrador por el momento), me sale el siguiente error, que al profesor no le sale en el video:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al hacer click en autors, deberia llevarme a la pantalla donde se muestran los autores registrados(que en estos momentos no hay, ya que no puedo agregar nada porque me salta este error)

que es lo que puede estar pasando? de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Muestra las partes esenciales del código para poder ayudarte

Comment: Tal parece que no es has ejecutado las migraciones, con eso se crean las tablas. Es por eso que te sale que la relación `autor_autor` no existe. ¿Ejecutaste `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: si ejecute el comando y me sale este mensaje:                                                    Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply. y me sigue saliendo el error en el administrador.

Comment: Primero ejecuta este código `python manage.py makemigrations` y posteriormente `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: ya lo hice, ejecute ambos en ese orden, con makemigrations me dice que no hay cambios y cuando ejecuto migrate, sale no migrations to apply como indique mas arriba. lo que note es que cree los models y ejecute el comando y no se ha creado la carpeta migrations, donde deberian estar las migraciones, podra ser ese el error?

Comment: tienes que indicar el nombre de la aplicación después de  `makemigrations` de esta forma `python manage.py makemigrations app_name` te dejo esta liga 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.0/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: eso era ahora si me funciono, no ponia el nombre de la aplicación al ejecutar makemigrations, muchas gracias.

Comment: Muestra la imagen de tus urls, al parecer hiciste una relacion no acorde a las clases que has creado , revisa bien el codigo en tus modelos y has las migraciones correspondientes

Comment: @leo_vilchis podrias armar una respuesta con todo lo que fuiste diciendo?

Answer (score 2):

El problema radica en que no se están migrando las tablas.
Para solucionarlo simplemente tienes que ejecutar el siguiente código en este orden:

1. `python manage.py makemigrations app_name` es importante indicar el nombre de la app, de lo contrario no se realizara la migración.
2. `python manage.py migrate`

Con esto se realizara de manera correcta la migración de tus tablas y podrás utilizar el administrador de Django.

En este [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.0/intro/tutorial02/) encontraras más información.